# UPS GetRate() Shipping Server Error Log

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error, ups

Can someone help break this error down into plain English?  I'm seeing the following error in our server application logs but am not sure where exactly the error is occurring.  The library its referring to is the .NET Shipping library http://dotnetshipping.codeplex.com/releases/view/5241.

```
Event Type: Error

Event Source:   .NET Runtime

Description:
Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: 
System.Net.WebException
Stack:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
at dotNETShipping.ShippingProviders.UPSProvider.GetRates()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 1):

`The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.` means that you triggered an error that was not caught by a try/catch statement. From the events it is something that occured at your HttpWebRequest object.

Try wrapping your statements in a try/catch, specifically catching a WebExeception.

i.e

```
try
{
    ...
} 
catch (WebException wex)
{
    //add logging statements here. 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //add more logging here 
}
```

I suggest dumping everything you can about your web exception initially, and then depending upon the information returned correct the issues and reduce your logging to appropriate levels for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on the .Net Shipping Library? The exception stack trace above shows the exception is occurring in the dotNETShipping.ShippingProviders.UPSProvider.GetRates() method. If you are just using the library as a third party library, you need to do a bug report to the library's maintainers.